# Beautify and parse JSON dump to create readable email content

Tags: php, json, parsing, curl, formatting

I have a little php script on the server which takes a JSON dump of data from a curl command on a remote server.

The php script e-mails me via postmark the result however it just e-mails the raw JSON data at the moment which can be obviously quite unreadable.

I'd like to beautify and then parse the data if possible before sending it.

So the current php script is

```
<?php

$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
$serverToken = "*****";

 $json = json_encode(array(
    'From' => 'email',
    'To' => 'email',
    'Subject' => 'Server Info',
    'HtmlBody' => $payload,
    'TextBody' => $payload

));
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.postmarkapp.com/email');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'X-Postmark-Server-Token: ' . $serverToken
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

and I'd get e-mailed this...

```
{ "IP": "78.122.144", "SERIAL" : "C02SQ5888TUA", "Date", "Fri 23 Jun 2017 18:05:01 BST" }
```

A beautifier online would turn it into

```
{
"IP": "78.122.144",
"SERIAL": "C02SQ5888TUA",
"DATE": "Fri 23 Jun 2017 18:05:01 BST"
}
```

But i'd really like the content of the email to look like this...

```
 IP: 78.122.144
 SERIAL: C02SQ5888TUA
 DATE: Fri 23 Jun 2017 18:05:01 BST
```

With the {} " and , removed.

Could anyone suggest how to have the script/server do that, and the icing on the cake would be to put the serial number above into the subject of the email too.

An example curl command is:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://url.com/first.php -d '{ "IP Address": "'"$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)"'", "SERIAL": "'"$(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial/ {print $4}')"'", "Date", "'"$(date)"'" }'
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php and loop

Comment: It seems you have just posted your postmarkapp.com API authentication credentials. I've edited them out of the post but you'll want to change them **immediately**.

Comment: @AlexHowansky don't worry, I wasn't that daft, it's just a random number :)

Comment: OK great, it looked like a real key, so I wasn't sure. You would be surprised how often I see real API credentials posted here. :)

Comment: Haha I bet @AlexHowansky, thanks for removing just in case though! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this (replace the first line in your script with this)

```
 $payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $jsonArray = json_decode($payload);
 $payload = "";
 foreach($jsonArray as $key => $value){
      $payload .= $key . ": " . $value . "\n";
 }
```

That should make payload a pretty string.

To add the serial number to the email subject, all you'd need to do is

```
...
'Subject' => "Server Info " . $jsonArray['SERIAL'],
...
```

Or you could just do

```
$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
$payload = print_r($payload, true);
```

Comment: The first idea worked really well - but only with one command sent from curl - as soon as I added two, the e-mail wouldn't send. I've included an example curl command so you can see what's going on with the initial request.

Comment: .@Prodikl do you know how to make your first idea work with the Curl input example I gave?

Comment: Sorry I'm not really sure regarding the curl command (can't test that now). As for the subject I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make

```
$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
$payload = json_encode(json_decode($payload), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: That gave me "null" as the content of the e-mail unfortunately.